# Parallel assignment in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any way of doing parallel assignment in C++? Currently, the below compiles (with warnings)

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() { 
  int a = 4;
  int b = 5;
  a, b = b, a;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << endl
            << "b: " << b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and prints:

```
a: 4
b: 5
```

What I'd like it to print ... if it weren't obvious, is:

```
a: 5
b: 4
```

As in, say, ruby, or python.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not possible. Your code example

```
a, b = b, a;
```

is interpreted in the following way:

```
a, (b = b), a
```

It does nothing. The comma operator makes it return the value of a (the right most operand). Because assignment binds tighter, b = b is in parens.

The proper way doing this is just

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

Boost includes a tuple class with which you can do

```
tie(a, b) = make_tuple(b, a);
```

It internally creates a tuple of references to a and b, and then assigned to them a tuple of b and a.

Answer (score 4):

Parallel assignment is not supported in C++.  Languages that support this usually treat `a,b,c` as a list on either side of the assignment operator, this isn't the way the comma operator works in C++.  In C++, `a, b` evaluates a and then b, so `a, b = b, a` is the same as `a; b = b; a;`.

Answer (score 1):

Or Perl. But no, it's not possible (as far as I'm aware), you need to use a temporary variable, as in:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;

{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

FYI, internally those languages (or Perl atleast) create a temporary list `{ a, b }`, then assign the list to the two variables. In other words, this is atleast as performant, if only a little more messy.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old – I just stumbled into it today...
...and wondered why nobody gave this answer before...

I think, it's possible to do it in C++11 similar like Python does it (under the hood):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 4, b = 5;
  cout << "Before assignment: a: " << a << ", b: " << b << endl;
  pair<int&, int&> ba(b, a);
  ba = make_pair(a, b); // <===: (b, a) = (a, b)
  cout << "After assignment : a: " << a << ", b: " << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this out on [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/RXXG09). The output was:

```
Before assignment: a: 4, b: 5
After assignment : a: 5, b: 4
```

If I remember right (I'm not a Python expert), in Python, `a, b` denotes a pair. ([Python Doc.: 5.3. Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences))

Such pair can be done in C++ 11 easily e.g. with [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). In this case, I made a pair of references and assigned the pair of values. It works as the `make_pair()` loads both variables before the right pair (of values) is assigned to the left pair of references.

Scrolling again, I realize that this answer is close to the boost based solution of [Johannes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275149/7478597).

May be, the reason is that it didn't work in C++03. I tried in coliru.stacked-crooked.com: With `-std=c++03` it yields terrible to read compiler errors – changing to `-std=c++11` and it compiles and executes fine as described above.

**Disclaimer**

I just cannot imagine what this solution is good for nor what practical worth it may have. This is not what I tried to do. As many other answers states "It does not work." IMHO it does (spelling it right according to the C++ language)...

Answer (score 0):

Or Lua...
There are tricks with C/C++, like using xor or operations, but with risk of overflow and such. Just do it the painful way, with three assignments. Not a big deal.

Comment: might want mention the xor trick also only works on integral types.  Also, integer promotion would keep it from overflowing but two of the same type won't overflow with a xor operation 0b1110 xor 0b1010 will always be 0b1100 at it is a bitwise operation

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in the Standard Library. You could write a set of template functions :

```
template <typename T1> void ParAssign(T1& Lhs_1, T1 const& Rhs1);
template <typename T1, typename T2> void ParAssign(T1& Lhs1, T2& Lhs2, T1 const& Rhs1, T2 const& Rhs2);
// etc.
ParAssign(a,b,
          b,a);
```

That's non-trivial if there is aliasing, as in your swap example.

Comment: std::swap( a, b )