# Is it ok to wrap code in anonymous namespaces for using directives?

Tags: c++

I want `using namespace std;` to apply to classes as well as functions without polluting the global namespace, but I'm wondering if it's an ok approach.

```
namespace
{
    using namespace std;
    class S
    {
    public:
        S()
        {
            cout << "ok";
        }

        friend ostream operator<<(ostream& os, const S& s);
    };
}
```

Any caveats to this?

Comment: So long as it's in your own source file (NOT header) and any other coders working on the file don't mind, it's ok.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Don't take the decision to use an anonymous namespace just so you can limit the scope of a `using` directive.**

That being said, if an anonymous (or any other) namespace is already there and you want the advantages of the `using` inside it, it's fine as long as your coding standards okay it.

Comment: Why are you **shouting**?

Answer (score 1):

It will work but keep in mind the following points:

- You should limit its use in a source file, not in a header file (in general [you should refrain from using unnamed namespaces in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357564/uses-for-anonymous-namespaces-in-header-files) since they can easily mess around with your symbol definitions, especially if there are inline functions that use something from the anonymous namespace).
- It's a bad practice and adding an additional naming hierarchy layer (i.e. the anonymous namespace) just for laziness is as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in header file then it's not preferable as this file could be included in multiple source file. If in some source file then its acceptable

Comment: @NeilKirk what do you mean? You can have anonymous namespaces in headers just fine.

Comment: @NeilKirk I learnt you can have anonymous namespaces in header as well.

Comment: I stand corrected. They are allowed. Although not a good idea, as it will duplicate the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this looked like a great solution, in my experiments it doesn't do as I expected it would. It doesn't limit the scope of the using directive.

**Consider this:**

```
#include <string>

namespace {

string s1; // compile error

}

namespace {

string s2; // compile error

}

string s3; // compile error

int main()
{
}
```

None of those strings compile because they are not properly qualified. This is what we expect.

**Then consider this:**

```
#include <string>

namespace {

using namespace std;

string s1; // compiles fine (as expected)

}

namespace {

string t2; // compiles fine (I didn't expect that)

}

string v3; // compiles fine (I didn't expect that either)

int main()
{
}
```

<strike>So placing a using directive within an unnamed namespace appears to be exactly the same as placing it in the global namespace.</strike>

**EDIT:** Actually, placing a symbol in an unnamed namespace makes it local to the translation unit. So this is why it can't work for the intended purpose.

Therefore it has to be a no-no for headers.

Answer (score 0):

An unnamed namespace doesn't **contain** the effects of a *using-directive*:

```
namespace A {int i;}
namespace {
  using namespace A;
}

int j=i,k=::i;        // OK
```

Both qualified and unqualified lookup follow the implicit *using-directive* for the unnamed namespace and then follow the explicit one within it.  Wrapping the unnamed namespace inside **another** namespace limits the unqualified case to other code within that outer namespace, of course:

```
namespace A {int i;}
namespace B {
  namespace {
    using namespace A;
  }
  int j=i;              // OK, as above
}

int j=i,                // error: i not found
    k=B::i;             // OK
```

However, in either case you might as well write the *using-directive* outside the unnamed namespace (or not write it at all if it would be problematic, perhaps because it would appear in a header file).