# Are static or unnamed namespace still useful when header and implementation are separated?

Tags: c++, static, unnamed-namespace

As answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c), I learnt that the `static` keyword to the function means it can only be seen from the functions in that file. I think unnamed namespace can be used for the same purpose.

However, usually, implementation and header files are separated. So, it seems to me that a programmer can hide all the "private stuff" inside the implementation file by not writing the declaration of such private stuff in the header file.

Considering above, when are `static` and unnamed namespaces helpful? The only case I can come up with is where multiple implementation files correspond to a single header file.

Comment: if not static/ inside namespace, the symbols are visible from translation unit and ODR still applies.

Comment: Putting a static declaration or anonymous namespace declaration in a header file is not very useful.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah, that makes sense

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Or they use it willingly, against the creators' best wishes (and security practicies)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You should turn that comment into an answer.  I would like to up vote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping a definition in implementation file does not make it private in any sense. Any other header or implementation file can declare that function and use it. It's not always a bad thing - I used parts of private implementations of libraries when I really needed it (but I do not recommend doing that).

The worse part of having such not-so-private implementation is its potential for One Definition Rule violation. ODR states that every* function or variable must have exactly one definition in the whole program. If there is more than one definition, behaviour is undefined**.
This means that when you have your not-so-private implementation in your file and nobody knows about it, they can unknowingly write a function with the same name and arguments and get an ODR violation.

It would be a good practice to use `static` or anonymous namespace for all free functions that should be limited to a single file. Functions that need to be used from other files cannot use this strategy, so to limit the risk of ODR violations you should use descriptive names and perhaps (named) namespaces. Just make sure [you don't overuse namespaces](https://abseil.io/tips/130).

---

Note: using anonymous namespaces doesn't make sense in header files. Anonymous namespace limits the scope of its content to the translation unit in which it exists, but header files are copied and pasted into (potentially) multiple TUs. The one use of anonymous namespaces is in header-only libraries, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357564/uses-for-anonymous-namespaces-in-header-files) - it allows to create global objects in header file without ODR violation (but at a cost that each TU has its own copy of that variable).

---

*except for template functions, `inline` functions, functions defined in class definition and a couple more. Even then, all definitions must be exactly the same.

**When I encountered it once, linker used random definition, whichever it saw at that moment. Hilarity and long debugging sessions ensued.