# What is the difference in assignment between C and Python?

Tags: python, c, variables, recursion, fibonacci

```
A = 0
B = 1

A, B = B, A + B
```

running 5 times:

the values of B in Python will be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5.
the values of B in C will be 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.

Would anyone explain this to me?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE (1 == 1);
#define FALSE (1 == 0);

int fibonacci(int sequencia);

int main() {
    fibonacci(5);
    return FALSE;
}

int fibonacci(int sequencia) {
    static int antigo = 0;
    static int novo = 1;
    static int copia = 0;

    if (sequencia == 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    else {
        printf("%i\n", novo);
    }
    antigo, novo = novo, antigo + novo;
    fibonacci(sequencia - 1);
}
```

```py
antigo = 0
novo = 1

def fibonacci(sequencia):
    global antigo, novo
    if sequencia != 0:
        print novo

    else:
        return True

    antigo, novo = novo, antigo + novo
    fibonacci(sequencia - 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fibonacci(5)
```

Comment: `a, b = b, a` in python and C mean _very, very different_ things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275128/parallel-assignment-in-c

Comment: In general, you shouldn't expect different languages to have the same semantics even where they have identical syntax.

Comment: `antigo, novo = novo, antigo + novo;` in C does not do what you think it does. Here's what happens:

1: evaluate `antigo` and discard the result.
2: assign `novo` to `novo`.
3: evaluate `antigo+novo` and return it (but since you're not assigning the value it is still discarded).

Comment: A bit strange to close this with a dup for C++, in my opinion. It's not obvious that they are the same in this respect (either).

Comment: @unwind Agree, I followed the link and found that it's not that difficult (now and in C++11 with `std::pair`). But these things are not available in C. (And, I must smile remembering all these comments "C and C++ are two separate lanuages...")

Comment: C and C++ do not support multiple assignment the way Python does.  In C and C++, the statement `A, B = B, A + B` is parsed as `(A), (B = B), 
(A + B)` and evaluated as "evaluate `A` and discard the result, then assign `B` to `B`, then evaluate `A + B` and discard the result."  To do what you want in C, you'd have to use two separate assignment statements - `A = B; B = A + B;`

Comment: John Bode and Zinki Your answers were enlightening, thank you.